# Zora doesn't allow NFT 1 of 1 editions?

Tags: blockchain, erc-721, nft

Zora is decentralized marketplace for NFTs that doesn't take any fees from sales of NFTs, built on the Ethereum blockchain. Zora's [help docs](https://help.zora.co/en/articles/4876845-how-does-zora-work) says

> Instead of creating artificial scarcity by selling copies of digital
> goods (like on Bandcamp or Gumroad,) we propose an alternative: make
> one original openly accessible to everyone no matter who owns it, and
> sell that original token over and over again.

Does this mean that the NFTs that are sold on Zora's marketplace are not scarce 1 of 1 editions, like how the crypto art platform SuperRare encourages?

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that the NFTs that are sold on Zora's marketplace are not scarce 1 of 1 editions

I don't think that's what they're saying.

The FAQ seems to be targeted at people who are unfamiliar with the idea of NFTs in general. The comparisons it's making are to real-world, off-chains product, rather than to other NFT platforms.

They said:

> we propose an alternative: make one original openly accessible to everyone no matter who owns it, and sell that original token over and over again

Taking a piece of Beeple artwork as an example, this is saying that anyone can access the artwork - i.e. by browsing the IPFS URL - regardless of the owner. The owner can't restrict access to it. This is in contrast to a piece of music on Bandcamp (their example), where each user must purchase their own copy to be able to listen to it.

Comment: i got the URL access part fine, but your Bandcamp statement where "each user must purchase their own copy" conflicts with the FAQ saying "sell that original token over and over again", which I interpret as: sell multiple copies, or originals, to whoever wants it. I think their FAQ wording is meant to be "allow the original token to be resold over and over again", but this as well conflicts with the idea that whoever wants to listen to the song must pay to own a copy.

Comment: Overall, the Zora listings give no details about the number of editions there are for any of the items, which is alot different than other NFT platforms, and is what baffled me, since i can't right away see what metadata is requested when minting at Zora. I'm starting to think that even SuperRare, Raribles, etc don't even have a "number of editions" field in the metadata of their respective tokens during minting

Comment: Okay, good questions. Your second comment first: for the other platforms, each of the editions of a particular NFT have their own NFT ID (meaning they're really separate NFTs), which is why there's no "edition" field in the metadata. For example, Beeple's "Politics is Bullshit" has 100 editions. Edition 66 is tokenID 100030066, whereas edition 25 is tokenId 100030025.

Comment: First comment: I took that to mean the (single, unique) item can resold over and over again through a chain of buyers and sellers, not that there can be multiple copies. So there's one copy, owned by one person, but anyone can view it (via IPFS). Like a picture (owned by a museum, or an art collector) being on show in a public (free) picture gallery.

Comment: ok these simply clarify we are in the same page of what the FAQ is actually saying. But, unlike owning a painting, ownership of a song (nevermind the masters) by *only one* person is unheard of